# xcode generates the error: library not found for -lGTMOAuth2

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, clang

When I run xcode, it generates:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/Marigold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dcvtelabdpuejxffyojvoivgykqw/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GTMOAuth2'
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/Marigold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dcvtelabdpuejxffyojvoivgykqw/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher'
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/Marigold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dcvtelabdpuejxffyojvoivgykqw/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleAPIClientForREST'
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/Marigold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dcvtelabdpuejxffyojvoivgykqw/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/Marigold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dcvtelabdpuejxffyojvoivgykqw/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Protobuf'
>
> ld: library not found for -lGTMOAuth2
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: Check if there is an xcode workspace file to open instead of the xcode project file

Comment: JeanLuck I also run the workspace file but this file also generate an error."symbols not found for arm64.

Comment: Make sure you enabled arm64 in the unity player settings and you are not using any outdated plugins that don‘t support arm64.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode not able to find these files.

Go to build Setting
search linking
double click on that remove library which is not available.
Clean and again build project.
Hope this will help.